# find standard deviation of days between valid verifications

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to calculate

1. avg days between valid verification
2. standard deviation of days between valid verification

For example i have a table psverify_interaction

```
mysql> show create table psverify_interaction\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: psverify_interaction
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `psverify_interaction` (
  `interaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `request_message_details` text,
  `verification_status` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitutde` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `longitude` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `ip_address` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `batch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interaction_channel` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`interaction_id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=381845 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Now I need to find for each customer

1. avg days between valid verification
2. standard deviation of days between valid verification

For avg days between valid verification for each customer can do like this

```
SELECT customer_id, 
DATEDIFF(MAX(time_stamp),MIN(time_stamp)) / (COUNT(time_stamp)-1) as 'avg days between valid verification'
FROM psverify_interaction 
AND verification_status = 'valid' 
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Now i need to find "standard deviation of days between valid verification for each customer" , How can i find it in query

**Example data**

```
SELECT interaction_id,customer_id,time_stamp FROM psverify_interaction WHERE customer_id = 352 and  verification_status = 'valid';
+----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| interaction_id | customer_id | time_stamp          |
+----------------+-------------+---------------------+
|          60809 |         352 | 2010-04-07 08:22:02 |
|          88703 |         352 | 2010-05-11 02:08:02 |
|          88888 |         352 | 2010-05-19 00:20:02 |
|          88889 |         352 | 2010-05-19 00:28:07 |
|          90024 |         352 | 2010-08-09 11:09:02 |
+----------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

So for this avg days between valid verification can be calculated like

```
SELECT customer_id, DATEDIFF(MAX(time_stamp),MIN(time_stamp)) / (COUNT(time_stamp)-1) 
FROM psverify_interaction 
WHERE customer_id = 352
AND verification_status = 'valid' 
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Comment: I need to find standard deviation of days between valid verification , I hope it would not work there, I have added some sample data.

Comment: You need to generate a derived table that contains the difference between successive rows. Then use `STD` on that column.

Comment: Can you please let me know, how can i do that.

Comment: Like I asked before, what have you tried? We're not here to do your programming for you, we're here to help you fix the problems in your code. Do some research, you should be able to find other questions on SO or other sites showing how to do it.